# C# XNA - Inventory/destructable terrain & collection

Tags: c#, .net, xna, inventory

I can't describe the problem well enough in the title. If somone has edit permissions and can phrase it better, feel free to.

So I've got a nice little terrain going, it's destructable and all, but if somone, say, breaks a tree, how can I make it add a tree to their inventory?

I'm not looking for code, just a method.

Each block has it's own class all inheriting from the base class Block, and when the block is destroyed, it drops a sort of pickup-able baby block.

I'm able to do this, but I'm confused because the idea is you can break blocks and place them somewhere else (Yeah, kinda like Minecraft), so how would I make this inventory system work? I've been thinking for two days and I got nothing.

Comment: So, you can get a broken block to drop an item, and you're wondering how to get that item into the inventory, or something else?

Comment: Prety much. I'm wondering how to drop the item. I guess I could do something like (new DroppedItem(ItemToBeRemoved.Texture)), but I'm wondering how to tell the dropped item what item to give the player when they pick it up. I think I was reading something about reflection doing what I'm wanting but I've got a worse memory than a goldfish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explaining it with words I figured it will be easier with some pseudo code:

```
public enum MaterialType
{
    Wood,
    Stone,
    Count // this should always be the last one
}

public class Block
{
    MaterialType m_type;
}

public class Player
{
    MaterialType m_inventory[MaterialType.Count];
}

// call this when you break a block
public class World
{
    public void OnBlockDestroyed()
    {
        player.m_inventory[block.m_type]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Items need some sort of ID code.  You obviously already have one to store the world itself.

The block had a type of "tree" when you chopped it.

"Tree" + Chop => "Chopped tree"

When it's picked up you remove the chopped tree graphic from the world and put a chopped-tree item in the player's inventory.

Comment: So basically I just do something like this: if (item.name == "chopped wood") {inventory.add block(wood)} etc etc?

Comment: Basically, but you'll likely want a better way of doing things than hardcoding it.

Comment: @AshleyDavies: Why would you look at text?  You already have a block ID you used to draw it, use that!